# Where is my Azure Database login's password?

Tags: sql-server, azure

Just created a new SQL database in Azure Portal, called 'mydatabase'. It automatically created a SQL login called 'mydatabaseweb' when the datasbe was created. Problem is, I can't seem to locate the password for this new login. Anyone know where this thing is? Or how to manage the logins via the portal?

Answer (score 0):

Answer to this one here: [Password reset for Azure database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790752/password-reset-for-azure-database)

Still not entirely certain how I missed that in the first place :/