# How to log into SQL Server as Admin in SQL Server 2012 Management Studio

Tags: sql-server, azure, ssms

I am very new to SQL Server. I am trying to execute this T-SQL code in SQL Server Management Studio:

```
INSERT INTO Stickers (Name, Category, Gender, ImageData)
   SELECT   
       'Red Dress',
       'Dress',
       'F',
       BulkColumn FROM OPENROWSET(Bulk '\\Mac\Home\Documents\MMImages\reddress.png', 
                                  SINGLE_BLOB) AS BLOB
```

but I get this error:

> You do not have permission to use the bulk load statement.

So I researched how to get permission. I found a lot of answers. But I have to be logged in as Admin to perform the necessary actions to grant myself the ability to use the bulk load statement.

I have tried connecting to the server using username Admin, password Admin. I am using Azure to host my database.

How do I log in as Admin?

Comment: Try resetting the Admin user password for the database. There are several solutions to do that in this question's answer. http://stackoverflow.com/q/13790752/325521 ... one of them should work.

Comment: @Shiva Thanks, that worked. I realised that my user is actually already the administrator while doing that :P Not sure why none of the answers to give me permission to use bulk load were working then.