# Cannot access Azure SQL database

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio, azure, azure-sql-database

I am having trouble accessing my Azure SQL database. I Have whitelisted my ip address(using 'what is my ip' in google to find it) The connection string in the azure portal is -

> Driver={SQL Server Native Client
>   10.0};Server=tcp:nrmuolxpqg.database.windows.net,1433;Database=databasename;Uid=username@nrmuolxpqg;Pwd={your_password_here};Encrypt=yes;Connection
>   Timeout=30;

What do I put into the Migration Tool, or into visual studio as the connection properties? In particular what to do with the 'tcp' at the starte of the server string?

The fields I need to fill in are:

-Server name (do I need to put tcp or the port number in here? )

-Login

-password - (this is my windows account password right? )

-Database

Answer (score 2):

The only thing you need to change is the username and password. This is something you specified when you created the server. It's not the same as your Windows username and password.

If you forgot the password, you can reset following these instructions, [Password reset for Azure database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790752/password-reset-for-azure-database).

**EDIT 06/20/2018 - Finding the username**

If you forgot your username, you can find it by clicking the *Show database connection strings* link in the Essentials window.

[image]

The ADO.NET connection string will not show the username but any of the other examples will.

[image]

Here are a few additional things you can try to resolve connection issues.

Try pinging the server. The server doesn't respond to the request but the name should be resolved to an IP address.
[image: Pinging server]

Verify that your client IP address has been added as a firewall rule.
[image: Client IP]

Make sure you are using the correct connection string (in your question you are using the ODBC connection string, you might want to try the ADO.NET one). Also double-check that you use the correct username and password.
[image: Connection strings]

To connect from Visual Studio, add a connection from the Server Explorer window using the server name and login info as shown below. Obviously you have to change the server name and login info to match you specifics. I'm connecting to a database called StackDemo in the below screenshot.
[image: Visual Studio connection]

If you still can't connect, there might be an issue where your company's or personal firewall is blocking the connection.

Comment: Unless you are trying to use the public preview of Azure Active Directory Authentication for Azure SQL DB. See https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/sql-database-aad-authentication/. Then you would want Authentication=Active Directory Integrated;

Comment: Thanks I've reset my password, but i am still getting this error.
A network-related or instance-specific error occured while establishing a connection to SQL server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify the instance name is correct and the SQL server is configured to allow remote connections. error 25 connection string is not valid.

Comment: I can't even ping the database address above?!

Comment: @GMan I added a few more details.

Comment: can you tell me what is the user name here ? or where it shows user in azure online web ?

Comment: @Ahmad is added info on where to find the username.