# Azure is hanging when creating databases

Tags: database, azure

I'm recreating my development databases in Azure. I have been able to delete/create new ones for over 100 times in the past 3 days with no issue. Small amount of times until the database is fully created, but not too bad. 
Today, Saturday, the database is not created and it is not updated probably. So, if I start the DB creation like this: (see pic1)
[image]

it says that it is validated and then gives me the message that Deployment has Started, but no DB is created (see pic2)
[image]

so, I check the audit log and it claims that the DB deployment has succeeded per (see pic3)[image]

but still my database list is still empty (see pic4) and the darn deployment started is still spinning
[image]

I have already tried signing out/in and different browser, but no luck, Is there anything else I could do!? I need my DB.

Comment: This seems like a transient Azure issue - so... off-topic for StackOverflow. Just keep an eye on [Azure Status](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/status/) if something isn't working right.

Comment: @DavidMakogon how is it unrelated and yours not. You had edited and answered a similar question? http://stackoverflow.com/q/13790752/1019042

Comment: Yours is due to a transient outage; once the outage (or transient issue) is fixed, the issue is no longer reproducible, and no longer valid). The question you're referring to is not - it's related to resetting a password for a database (a built-in feature available all the time, and nothing to do with an outage).

Comment: thank you for fully explaining it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into similar issues. This is an issue with azure. All you have to do is wait it out.

I remember I had this issue on a sunday night, then monday morning it was working perfectly fine.

Comment: I am thinking weekend have something to do with it. thx. I've been waiting for so long, but I'll continue waiting

Comment: @user1019042 No worries, it happens here and there. A few days ago it took me around 15 mins to deploy a small SQL database. If it doesnt work now, I would suggest trying again in a few hours, or best next day.

Comment: This is, at best, a comment - not an answer. Not a topic for StackOverflow. Also (not that it matters, but...) the weekend has zero to do with Azure operations.

Comment: still was helpful to know that it's happened before to someone and that it comes back. btw: @SA, it did come back. thx