# Azure SQL database is not designed to allow users change their passwords. Any workaround?

Tags: sql-server, azure

We start with the facts:

- Logins are in the *master* database,
- users are in a user database.
- Azure does not allow to change database with USE statement.
- SQL requires the user to be in the *master* database in order to execute ALTER LOGIN statement.

.

```
--USE master;
--**ERROR** USE statement is not supported to switch between databases. Use a new connection to connect to a different database.
--GO
ALTER LOGIN nonadmin WITH PASSWORD='new5as$word' OLD_PASSWORD='old5a$sword';
--**ERROR** User must be in the master database. 
GO
```

It is possible to migrate the database to contained mode, but this way would be quite exhausting as the legacy code have plenty of places like this:

```
IF(OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#temp1') IS NOT NULL)
BEGIN
  DROP TABLE #temp1
END;

CREATE TABLE #temp1
(
  id int not null IDENTITY,
  CONSTRAINT PK_tt1 PRIMARY KEY(id)
)
```

Is there a suitable workaround except migrating to contained database mode?

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Why do you assume that Azure SQL isn't designed to allow password changes? What type of user is this? Contained users don't have logins, you'd need to use ALTER USER. LOGIN is a server login, which is saved in master.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are trying to change the password of a contained user. Contained users don't have server logins so you can't use the `ALTER LOGIN` statement.

You need to use [ALTER USER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176060.aspx) :

```
ALTER USER nonadmin WITH PASSWORD='new5as$word' OLD_PASSWORD='old5a$sword';
```

A server login is the identity with which you login to a server. In SSMS, you'll find logins in a server's Security node. These logins are then granted access to specific databases as users. These users are stored in the `master` database.

Comment: Actually Azure SQL service does support server logins (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-login-transact-sql?view=azuresqldb-current). You can create a login (when connected to the `master` database and with appropriate privileges) and then create users for this login in any database on the same Azure SQL Server. In this scenario you do have a problem of having to allow connection to `master` to that login, to allow changing the password for the account.

Answer (score 1):

elect the Database choice on the left, then select Servers:
[image]

Then, after selecting the server of choice, you'll see the option on the right for resetting admin password:
[image]

source : [Password reset for Azure database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790752/password-reset-for-azure-database)

Comment: This only works for the Azure SQL Server instance administrator account - does not work for any other created logins/users.