# Azure SQL Database

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have an Azure Free Trial account and have mis-placed the password for the Admin user I created.  Is there a way to reset the p/w or do I need to create another database?

Comment: probably a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13790752/password-reset-for-azure-database

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you can login to you Azure portal, go to the SQL Server blade and there is an option at the top "Reset password".

Make sure you are looking at the server, not the database.

[image]